# What happens if I call QProcess::start() again?

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QProcess * process` declared as class member and I allocated in constructor with `process = new QProcess'. Now when user press a button, I start the process.

```
void MainWindow::rsync()
{
    process->start("rsync c:\\test\\sync1 root@10.0.0.1:/Test");

    // additionally what will happen if I do this
    // process->start("ping root@10.0.0.1");
}
```

Now the sync can take upto 30 seconds, what happens if I press the button again within this time? What happens if I press the button again after the first sync is complete? Can I call `start()`method again on QProcess object I allocated once or do I have delete it and reallocate it?

Part of the reason I am asking is the first `start`command does't quite work (rsync seems to be blocked or doesn't display any messages) but the 2nd `start()` with `ping`command works and I can see output in my application.

Comment: As an aside: you can simply have `QProcess process` as a class member, no need to use explicit memory management here. You'll save one heap allocation that way, and have one less potential bug to worry about. Think of: `class MainWindow { Q_OBJECT QProcess m_process; ... };`

Answer (score 2):

From Qt docs:

> If the QProcess object is already running a process, a warning may be printed at the console, and the existing process will continue running unaffected.